# NGUI "Too many vertices on one panel" in edit mode

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, vertices, ngui

We're using NGUI for our UI in our current Unity game, and for whatever reason, when viewing the UI in the inspector, it will randomly bug out, fail to draw, and throw the "Too many vertices in one panel" error, listing 75,548 vertices as being drawn. That seems like a ludicrous number of vertices for what we're doing.

Here's some images to clarify:

When I first insert my prefab object into the scene, it loads properly and shows correctly:

[image: Before the Error]

However, after I change any attribute that causes it to reload (namely in this example, the OnClick() functionality of any button), it throws a "Too many vertices error" as shown:

[image: After the Error]

Notice in the second image that the toolbar has completely disappeared and is failing to be drawn as well.

The other thing is that **when I run the scene, everything functions perfectly.** So, it's just an issue with NGUI's editor code and I can't quite figure out what's happening.

Anyone have an idea?